# Cannot get the SelectedValue of the Drop Down List ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

ok, when i want to get the SelectedValue of the dropdownlist when i click
a button, but the SelectedValue always return "" (nothing), 
please help me thanks!

here is the source

```
    <tr>
    <th style="float:left">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcategory" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnsearch" runat="server" Height="20px" ImageUrl="~/img/search.png" OnClick="btnsearch_Click" Width="20px" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnsearch" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Search.aspx">Advanced Search</asp:LinkButton>
    </th>
    </tr>
```

and here is the code behind

```
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindDataList();
            BindDropDown();
        }
    }

    private void BindDataList()
    {
        string cmd = "SELECT top 3 product_id, product_name, brand, imgurl FROM product ORDER BY NEWID()";
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        DataList1.DataSource = dt;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }

    private void BindDropDown()
    {
        string cmd = "select category_id, category_name from category";
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        ddlcategory.DataTextField = "category_name";
        ddlcategory.DataValueField = "category_id";
        ddlcategory.DataSource = dt;
        ddlcategory.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Product/Product.aspx?category_id=" + ddlcategory.SelectedValue.ToString() + "&search=" + txtsearch.Text);
    }
}
```

and this is the result when i click btnsearch
"http://localhost:1345/Product/Product.aspx?category_id=&search=something"
as you can see that that ddlcategory.SelectedValue.ToString() 
return "", what's wrong?

Comment: Just a heads up - the URL you provided is for your localhost, so no one but you can reach it.

Comment: When you view source for the dropdown in your browser, what do you see?  Does it have both text and values?

Comment: i know, i just want to clarify that the ddlcategory.SelectedValue.ToString()  return nothing. and i am sure that there are some data on the datasource.

Comment: yes, i checked the source, it has both text and values

Comment: <option value="1">laptop</option>
<option value="2">mobile</option>

Comment: If you hard-code a few ListItems in the HTML instead of binding in the code-behind, can you get the SelectedValue?

Comment: yes, i tried, it can get the SelectedValue ..... what's the problem... this is driving me crazy

Comment: Ha ha ha! I am wondering if using a DataSet instead of a DataTable would make any difference. I have no technical reason to say that; I just notice that I always use DataSets (and bind to the first table).

Comment: ok, thanks for your idea! i will try it tomorrow, it's 5:13am in Hong Kong

Comment: i tried using dataset, the problem is still here. However, when i use the SqlDataSource asp control to bind the dropdownlist, it works....

Answer (score 1):

Damn, i spent hours, and finally solve this problem.
The problem is that the EnableViewState is set to false in the master page (the parent Control). and all you need is set it back to true. even if the DropDownList (child control) is enabled viewstate, it also need to determine on the parent control. i.e. the EnableViewState in the parent control is set to false, the child control will also be false.